# If a browser already has cached a file with max-age=31536000 and I lower to max-age=600, will the browser understand and request the file again?

Tags: caching, cache-control

I am wondering if a browser that already have cached a file with the settings max-age=31536000 will understand that I have changed the max-age settings and therefore request a new file? Or will it wait till its cache has expired (after one year) and then ask for a new file?

Thanks in advance for your help! I haven't been able to find the answer, I'm not a programmer yet (but interested in programming) so I might be using the incorrect terms.

Answer (score 0):

If you serve a resource with `max-age=31536000` to a cache, it doesn't need to contact the origin server again until that time has expired.

> Or will it wait till its cache has expired (after one year) and then ask for a new file?

Yes, it can do this.

The only way it could learn about the new `max-age` is to contact the origin server again, and you've expressly said it doesn't need to do that.

Set your `max-age` responsibly.